# Error while bootstrapping ec2 instance on hosted chef server on azure

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, bootstrapping, knife

I am trying to bootstrap ec2 instance using knife on chef server hosted on azure marketplace. the chef client run fails throwing the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\xyz\chef-repo> knife ec2 server create -I ami-25c00c46 -f t2.micro 
--region ap-southeast-1 -N ec2module
-x ubuntu -i abc.pem -r "role[ec2], role[jenkinserver]" -g sg-9f1b31fa sudo

.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "ec2module" 
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com Running handlers:
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [2016-01-20T11:39:26+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com Running handlers complete
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [2016-01-20T11:39:26+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [2016-01-20T11:39:26+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [2016-01-20T11:39:26+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [2016-01-20T11:39:26+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [2016-01-20T11:39:26+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: chef --version
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.10.0
chef-client version: 12.5.1
berks version: 4.0.1
kitchen version: 1.4.2

Comment: Can you paste the `/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out` file, please?

Comment: Where can I find this file on windows workstation?

Comment: It should be in your bootstrapped instance (t2.micro, ubuntu?).

Comment: It is throwing an error when I tried to view its contents

Comment: An error when showing a file? What error? You need to login manually into the machine and `cat` the file.

Comment: Generated at 2016-01-21 09:14:02 +0000
NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/ssl.rb:214:in `verify_wildcard'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/ssl.rb:196:in `verify_hostname'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/ssl.rb:161:in `block in verify_certificate_identity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/ssl.rb:159:in `each'

Comment: And it goes on when I used cat

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the server SSL certificate and perhaps it is related to [Chef issue #4301](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4301) (read it).

Try [downloading the SSL certificate from the Chef Server](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssl_fetch.html):

```
> knife ssl fetch
```

Then, you can [check it with](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssl_check.html):

```
> knife ssl check
```

I hope this helps.